# C++ Solaris Uppercase conversion for special characters does not work

Tags: c++, utf-8, solaris, uppercase

I am using following code to do uppercase conversion. 
The strings in my software are UTF8 encoded. The following code works fine on Windows, AIX and Linux ( all 64 bit) however it does not work on Solaris (SunOS 5.10 Generic_147440-01 sun4u sparc SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise).

On Solaris the special characters such as "ä" are not getting converted to their uppercase equivalent. However , the ASCII characters such as 'a', 'b' etc are getting properly converted to the uppercase.

```
void String::MakeUpperUTF8()
{
    WCHAR *pwstr =  GetUnicode(); // Decode UTF8 encoded string to wide char string using iconv

     if (!pwstr)
    {
        return; // return if decode fails.
    }

    std::locale::global(std::locale("")); 
    const std::ctype<WCHAR>& f = std::use_facet< std::ctype<WCHAR> >(std::locale()); // using std //ctype facet and std locale convert string to uppercase   

    f.toupper(pwstr, pwstr + wcslen(pwstr)); 
    char *strPos = SetUnicode( pwstr, -1); // encode string back to UTF8

}
```

Can you please help me out. I am wondering why this code is not working on Solaris.

Comment: What is your default locale?

Comment: Can you give example to the result you've got? for example if you give the input "ä" (c3 a4), which character (and value) you've got instead of "Ä" (c3 84)?

Comment: My default locale is en_US.UTF-8. Following is the out put of locale command on solaris : LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
 LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

Comment: Character "ä" is not getting converted to any character . It remains unchanged. '001Öäabc' is my input string . This string gets converted to '001ÖäABC'. The special characters are ignored while uppercase concersion.

Comment: Perhaps your locale on Solaris is broken. [This works on Linux](http://ideone.com/Fc8aRL) and should work pretty much everywhere. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: By the way case conversion has very limited utility. I've never seen it used correctly, not once in my life. People are using it mostly for case-insensitive comparison, which is just plain wrong.

Comment: What is `WCHAR`? Assuming it is `wchar_t`, you probably don't have any UTF-8 used there, so that's a red herring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your help.

I solved my problem using following code.  Standard C++ facet does not work on Solaris. Hence I used towupper() Solaris API.

```
#if defined (SUN) || (__sun)
        for (long i=0; i < nWLength; ++i)
        {
            pwstr[i] = towupper(pwstr[i]);
        }
    #else
        const std::ctype<WCHAR>& f = std::use_facet< std::ctype<WCHAR> >(std::locale()); // using std ctype facet and std locale convert string to uppercase   
        f.toupper(pwstr, pwstr + nWLength); 
    #endif
```

Thanks,
Sumit

Answer (score 0):

The following code fails with any locale I've tried except `C`:

```
#include <locale>
int main() {
    std::locale::global( std::locale("") );
    return 0;
}
```

Built with (`-std=c++0x` seems to have no effect, also tried `-ansi` with the same result):

```
g++ -ggdb -Wall -std=c++0x solaris_locale.cc
g++ -ggdb -Wall solaris_locale.cc
```

Fails:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
$ ./a.out 
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Abort (core dumped)
```

Works:

```
$ LANG=C ./a.out
```

GDB backtrace gives:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xfe579265 in _lwp_kill () from /lib/libc.so.1
#1  0xfe57218a in thr_kill () from /lib/libc.so.1
#2  0xfe520fed in raise () from /lib/libc.so.1
#3  0xfe4f875d in abort () from /lib/libc.so.1
#4  0xfe7343d5 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler ()
    at /builds/hudson/workspace/nightly-update/build/i386/components/gcc45/gcc-4.5.2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vterminate.cc:93
#5  0xfe7313c5 in __cxxabiv1::__terminate (
    handler=0xfe734280 <__gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()>)
    at /builds/hudson/workspace/nightly-update/build/i386/components/gcc45/gcc-4.5.2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:39
#6  0xfe731422 in std::terminate ()
    at /builds/hudson/workspace/nightly-update/build/i386/components/gcc45/gcc-4.5.2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_terminate.cc:49
#7  0xfe731591 in __cxa_throw (obj=0x8061af0, tinfo=0xfe7652ec, 
    dest=0xfe725bb0 <~runtime_error>)
    at /builds/hudson/workspace/nightly-update/build/i386/components/gcc45/gcc-4.5.2/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/eh_throw.cc:83
#8  0xfe71e927 in std::__throw_runtime_error (
    __s=0xfe735e18 "locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid")
    at /builds/hudson/workspace/nightly-update/build/i386/components/gcc45/build/i86/i386-pc-solaris2.11/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:233
#9  0xfe72e790 in std::locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale (__cloc=@0xfeffec5c, 
    __s=0x8061254 "en_US.UTF-8") at c++locale.cc:66
#10 0xfe735e18 in .LC11 () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#11 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Machine info:

```
$ uname -a
SunOS os 5.11 11.1 i86pc i386 i86pc
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/gcc/4.5/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.11/4.5.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i386-pc-solaris2.11
Configured with: /builds/hudson/workspace/nightly-update/build/i386/components/gcc45/gcc-4.5.2/configure CC=/ws/on11update-tools/SUNWspro/sunstudio12.1/bin/cc CXX=/ws/on11update-tools/SUNWspro/sunstudio12.1/bin/CC --prefix=/usr/gcc/4.5 --mandir=/usr/gcc/4.5/share/man --bindir=/usr/gcc/4.5/bin --libdir=/usr/gcc/4.5/lib --sbindir=/usr/gcc/4.5/sbin --infodir=/usr/gcc/4.5/share/info --libexecdir=/usr/gcc/4.5/lib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc --enable-shared --with-gmp-include=/usr/include/gmp --with-mpfr-include=/usr/include/mpfr --without-gnu-ld --with-ld=/usr/bin/ld --with-gnu-as --with-as=/usr/gnu/bin/as CFLAGS='-g -O2 '
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.5.2 (GCC)
```

I would assume Solaris C++ locale support is incomplete/broken.

Comment: I suspect glibc locales != native locales, and libstdc++ only plays nicely with glibc. Perhaps you can try the same test linked to glibc, and also with the Sun's native compiler.

Comment: @n.m. I'm using `g++` version, which comes with OS, it is the only C/C++ compiler on the machine. I tested `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` in C program (not C++), built with `gcc` on the same machine and it seems to work (at least `mbstowcs()` works ok with UTF8). I think installing glibc from source would be irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Installing glibc from source would be a waste of time, as glibc can't be built/used on Solaris - it has no support for the Solaris system calls, only the Linux ones.

Comment: @alanc there's an OpenSoplaris port as far as I know

Comment: @alanc though I see it was not updated for quite a while, so probably it's not a good idea.

Comment: Perhaps moving to a newer GCC version would be a better idea as 4.5.2 is rather old.